# How to create an altimetry graph and interact with googlemaps

Tags: graph, highcharts

Good morning
I'm working with a not profit walking association, I would create a route with googlemaps and an interact altimetry graph.
I saw in the web many site with highcarts graph, this an example of web site that used highcharts to create an altimetry graph interactve with google maps https://londonedinburghlondon.com/route/

could help me to understand the correct procedure to create the interact graph?
Thanks for your support
Andrea

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: I suggest to start from reading documentation on Highcharts website https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart